# PHP syntax error unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) - not a missing semi-colon issue

Tags: php

Normally this is a semi-colon issue but not in this case. Cannot tell why this code isn't working and keeps generating

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:mywebdirectory\secure\OntCorpNFPNuansUpload.php on line 16

The data feeding it is just names, addresses and such - and no semi-colons there but its URL encoded anyways.

```
<?php

function sanitize_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

function printArray($array, $pad = '', $arrayName = '') {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            printArray($value, '', $key);
        } elseif (isset($value)) {
            $myString = $value;
            $myString = sanitize_input($myString);
            if ($arrayName != "") {
                echo $pad . "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"$key\"  name=\"" .     $arrayName . "[$key]\" value=\"$myString\">";
            } else {
                echo $pad . "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"$key\" name=\"$key\"  value=\"$myString\">";
            }
        }
    }
}


if(isset($_POST['NonProfitType'])) {
  $NonProfitType = sanitize_input($_POST["NonProfitType"]);
  } else {$NonProfitType = "";}


$postpath="";
if ($NonProfitType == "Charitable Corporation") {
$postpath="payment-nonprofit2b.php";

} else {$postpath="payment-nonprofit2.php";}
?>
```

It should just display the page with an upload form after this code but never gets that far.

Comment: There is no syntax error with that exact code. Either you got more code somewhere, or you're looking at the wrong file or old error-logs.

Comment: No its definitely the right page and the error is displayed on that page. Could it be a server configuration issue?

Comment: Also `sanitize_input()` is not fit for what it pretends to be.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comments Mario

Comment: See the linked reference under "syntax error does not transmit over the web"